# Which substitution string use for checksum in oracle apex5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5

We are using oracle apex 5 with database 12c. We want to create a custom URL in our application that contain checksum like -
`http://example.com/apex/f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.::NO::P12_ID:SY1740&cs=19A6E881BFF952EF0DE2A56492230996C`

Now, we know &SESSION. return session id, &APP_ID. return application id but what substitution string return check sum?

Answer (score 2):

You would use [APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#AEAPI160) to generate a url. The correct checksum would then be added. Since the checksum depends on the arguments and their values it wouldn't make sense to use a substitution string for this.
Example copied from API page:

```
DECLARE
    l_url varchar2(2000);
    l_app number := v('APP_ID');
    l_session number := v('APP_SESSION');
BEGIN
    l_url := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(
        p_url => 'f?p=' || l_app || ':1:'||l_session||'::NO::P1_ITEM:xyz',
        p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');
END;
```